Robust way to run a command after shortcut
I'd like to run a shell command (like xdg-open '${fileDirname}') when pressing F7. The only solutions I found involve workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence but this is not robust. E.g., if my terminal is already running a Python interpreter, this will send the sequence xdg-open ... to Python. Another alternative seems to be tasks, but as far as I see these cannot be global.
Is there any robust solution?
